# Select every second clip in Premiere Pro

Tags: premiere, editing, shotcut

After setting the cuts in a sequence, is there an easy way to select every second clip to delete them all at once.

Comment: You could use the kyboard shortcut sequence *down-arrow,  down-arrow, shift+delete*, repeat. That should delete every second clip. You could use something like autohotkey to do this (on windows).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [Autohotkey](https://autohotkey.com/download/) for Windows I could solve the Problem. If I had known this program before, I would have saved so much time!
After installing Autohotkey I just wrote a small script:

```
^+m::
    WinActivate, Adobe Premiere
    Send, d
    Send, +{del}
    Send, {Down}
Return
```

and saved it as *premiere.ahk* and double clicked it. Now I can use Ctrl+Shift+m to select the clip under the playhead and ripple delete it and move playhead to the next clip.

So now I just need to press Ctrl+Shift+m multiple times to delete every second clip. This is so much more convenient. You obviously can set the hotkey as you like. It doesn't have to be Ctrl+Shift+m.

I needed it on Windows, if someone needs alternatives for Autohotkey on macOS maybe you find something [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/153930/autohotkey-equivalent-for-os-x).

Answer (score 0):

When I'm editing my YouTube videos, my footage comprises silence, then a shot I want, then silence, then a shot I want, etc.  I do this as follows:

1. Select the whole clip.
2. Click on the timeline where I want to cut.
3. Press Ctrl-K to cut there.
4. Press **Shit-Delete** to delete the first part of clip.
5. Click on the clip again to select it.
6. Click on the timeline where I want to cut.
7. Press Ctrl-K to cut there.
8. Click on the clip to the *right*.
9. Click on the timeline where I want to cut.
10. Press Ctrl-K to cut there.
11. Press **Shift-Delete** to delete the clip to the left (the currently-selected clip).
12. Repeat.

This isn't exactly what you want, but it sounds as though our workflows are similar.  I just delete the clips I don't want as I'm making my cuts, by using Shift-Delete.

Comment: You can trim the start or end of a clip in 1 keystroke. Park the playheads where you want the in-point to be and hit the letter *q* This will ripple delete all of the selected clip from the start up to the current time. The letter *w* will trim the end to the current playhead position, doing a ripple edit as it does.